# MySQL query result fluctuating

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is more clear on this post: [Select all categories with latest post, user, and topic information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046159/select-all-categories-with-latest-post-user-and-topic-information)

——————————————————————————————————————————

I have a query that pulls a list of the categories for my forum along with the latest post in that category. The results come back as expected, except that sub_post information being pulled in the LEFT JOIN fp1 changes if if run the query several times.

I first noticed this problem when viewing my webpage and refreshing several times. The post that it is pulling fluctuates between 3 posts. I'm not sure how this is even possible, unless there is something wrong with the query.

Please, take a look at my query below and let me know if there is something I am doing wrong that might explain this odd behavior.

Cheers.

```
SELECT fc1.id AS cat_id, fc1.cat_name AS cat_name,
    fc1.cat_description AS cat_description, fc1.cat_views as cat_views, fp1.*
FROM forum_categories as fc1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT fp2.id AS sub_post_id,
                fp2.post_date as sub_post_date,
                fp2.post_topic as sub_post_topic,
                u2.id as sub_user_id, u2.username as sub_username,
                ft2.topic_subject as sub_topic_subject, ft2.topic_cat as sub_topic_cat
            FROM forum_posts as fp2
            LEFT JOIN users as u2 on fp2.post_by = u2.id
            LEFT JOIN forum_topics as ft2 on ft2.id = fp2.post_topic
            LEFT JOIN forum_categories as fcats on fcats.id = ft2.topic_cat
            ORDER BY fp2.id DESC)
as fp1 on fp1.sub_topic_cat = fc1.id
GROUP BY fc1.id;
```

EXPLAIN SELECT:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys           | key         | key_len | ref                | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | fc1        | index  | PRIMARY,cat_name_unique | PRIMARY     | 8       | NULL               |    3 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ref    | <auto_key0>             | <auto_key0> | 9       | tpw.fc1.id         |    9 | NULL        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | fp2        | index  | NULL                    | PRIMARY     | 8       | NULL               |   92 | NULL        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | u2         | eq_ref | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY     | 8       | tpw.fp2.post_by    |    1 | NULL        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ft2        | eq_ref | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY     | 8       | tpw.fp2.post_topic |    1 | NULL        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | fcats      | eq_ref | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY     | 8       | tpw.ft2.topic_cat  |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------+------+-------------+
```

I have 3 tables: forums_categories, forums_topics, and forums_posts. I am trying to list the categories along with the latest post in that category. The forums_post is linked to forums_topics by a post_topic and the forums_topics is linked to the forums_categories with a topic_cat.

Comment: When you use `GROUP BY`, it just picks a random row from the group.

Comment: If you want to get the first or last row in the group, use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Comment: Not sure , but why not like this -  select `ANY_COL` from post left join category ON any_condition  ( include more left joins according to requirements  )   , because in our case our main aim is to select the post not categories

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by _pala on this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30048334/4864675

I was going about the query wrong which accounted for the odd behavior. Thanks _pala!

Here's the SQL that worked it out for me provided by user _pala:

```
select fc.cat_name, fc.cat_description, fc.cat_views, u.username, fp.post_date, ft.topic_subject
  from forum_categories fc
inner join forum_topics ft
  on fc.id = ft.topic_cat
inner join forum_posts fp
  on fp.post_topic = ft.id
inner join users u
  on fp.post_by = u.id
inner join (
  select topic_cat, max(fp.id) most_recent_post
    from forum_topics ft
      inner join forum_posts fp
        on fp.post_topic = ft.id
  group by topic_cat
) q
  on q.topic_cat = ft.topic_cat
    and fp.id = q.most_recent_post;
```

Answer (score 0):

> LEFT JOIN forum_categories as fcats on fcats.id = ft2.topic_cat

I believe the inclusion of that LEFT JOIN has no impact on the result other than to slow down processing.  Remove it.

> ORDER BY fp2.id DESC

That ORDER BY has no impact on the result because the GROUP BY will not care.  Remove it.

If neither of those helps, then explain this:

> The post that it is pulling fluctuates between 3 posts.

And please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: I made your changes, but the query still doesn't behave correctly. What I mean by the post fluctuating is that when I run the query multiple times, I get different results for the info pulled in the fp1 LEFT JOIN. I get different posts pulled if I keep running the query which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have 3 tables: forums_categories, forums_topics, and forums_posts. I am trying to list the categories along with the latest post in that category. The forums_post is linked to forums_topics by a post_topic and the forums_topics is linked to the forums_categories with a topic_cat. I might be doing it all wrong.

Comment: Assuming your Answer works, you may as well "Accept" it, and ignore mine.